# I can't seem to find the right resolution for my computer 1280x720 is too big and 1024x768 isn't full screen

Tags: display, display-resolution

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 on a computer to use plugged hdmi into my 42 inch tv. In display settings im only offered 4 choices. the 1280x720 goes off the screen and the 1024x768 isn't full screen with no option in between. Very new to ubuntu. can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could try other options, such 1024 x 768, 1366 x 768 or others...

If you don't have those options available, you can still apply them to your monitor using [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/resolutionx/) program.